# Is it possible for msal-react to return a TokenCredential Object without using an interactive login?

Tags: msal.js, msal-react

So the use case for this is I'd like all users to be able to read files from a storage blob. I wasn't able to find a way to use existing MSAL tokens that the user has without forcing them to hit a login page as they're already authenticated by this point in the application.

[Here's a sample I found from Microsoft](https://github.com/Azure/blobindexreact/blob/main/web/src/blobs.js)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out InteractiveBrowserCredential is silent if the user is already logged in, it uses the currently active token or appears to as of the current version of msal-react.